# Reflect moveable element on keydown keeping position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a gif I use as a sprite that moves to wasd key presses. He faces left and I want to reflect him (horizontally) when he moves right. How do I do this? 
I thought to have 2 css classes and try to toggle them but nothing happened.

html

```
 <div class="sprite"><img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/iPuggAost1xde/giphy.gif" height="55" width="50" /></div>
```

css

```
.sprite {
      position: absolute;
      top: 48px;
      left: 540px;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      } 

  .sprite2 {
     position: absolute;
      top: 48px;
      left: 540px;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
    //reflect 
    -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    -ms-filter: fliph; 
    filter: fliph;
  }
```

js

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).keydown(function(key) {
        switch(key.which) {

            // a
            case 65:
                $(".sprite").animate({left: "-=10px"}, 'fast');
                break;

            // w
            case    87:
                $(".sprite").animate({top: "-=10px"}, 'fast');
                break;

            // d
            case 68:        
                $(".sprite").animate({left: "+=10px"}, 'fast');
        break;

            // s
            case 83:
                $(".sprite").animate({top: "+=10px"}, 'fast');
                break;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I should mention that I have removed my failed attempt at using js to toggle classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with jQuery but after searching a bit , I've end up with a working solution :

Added 2 class :

```
.right-img {
    -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    filter: FlipH;
    -ms-filter: "FlipH";
}

.left-img {
    -moz-transform: scaleX(1);
    -o-transform: scaleX(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

And adding them/removing them for the corresponding button :

```
$("img").removeClass("left-img");
$("img").addClass("right-img");
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ftfv3ddu/)

Comment: Consider accepting the answer if you think this solved your issue

Comment: So sorry, I'm new to slack and quite new to programming